# Is there syntax highlighting for DOS command line operations or DOS batch files?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

It doesn't look like there is (just grey code blocks), but perhaps I am missing a way to trigger it.

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108), no, there isn't.

Comment: Your command prompt doesn't even syntax highlight DOS commands. Why would you need an editor to color code that doesn't even have a defined set of colors? Just use `<!-- language: lang-none --> ` and be done with it...

Comment: Aaron: True, but most people's bash shells don't colorize anything either, yet there is a highlighter for bash.

Comment: @AaronBertrand my terminal has the option to colorized special words even though the shell itself has no similar function

Comment: @AaronBertrand powershell does highlight the commands, unlike cmd.exe

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->
```

Example

```vb
rem this is a comment
set here="is a string with spaces"
rem here are some keywords
call zulu
date zulu
do zulu
else zulu
erase zulu
exit zulu
for zulu
goto zulu
if zulu
in zulu
not zulu
```

Comment: But why? It seems illogical. Can you provide an explanation in the answer?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q no DOS specific highlighter is available, but the VB one is similar

Answer (score -1):

You can try `lang-dos`. It's a somewhat weak approach, but may be better than nothing:

```dos
@echo off
SET Var=Value
ECHO Var is now %Var%
"C:\Program Files\SomeCommand.exe" /?
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( EXIT /B 1 )
CALL OtherScript.cmd
REM etc.
```